# NSInvalidArgumentException in master-detail format

Tags: ios

I have an issue when I use Master-Detail format.

I set the following code in AppDelegate.m

```
FileContent1 *bug4 = [[FileContent1 alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lady Bug" 
    url1:@"file:///Users/daemonwolf/Desktop/11.htm" 
    rating:1 
    thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ladybugThumb.jpg"] 
    fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ladybug.jpg"]];

NSMutableArray *bugs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bug1, bug2, bug3, bug4, nil];

UINavigationController * navController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
MasterViewController * masterController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
masterController.bugs = bugs;
```

In MasterViewController.h, I set:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *bugs;
```

and in MasterViewController.m:

```
@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize bugs = _bugs;
```

But when I debug it, I get following exception:

> [UINavigationController setBugs:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7179250 2013-06-20 23:38:01.406 EBS[4682:11303] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController
>   setBugs:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7179250'

Why does this happen?

Comment: This probably means, that the first ViewController (`objectAtIndex:0`) in the `rootViewController` isn't a `MasterViewController`, but a `UINavigationController`.

You should check that.

Comment: thx:) But how to set it?